# Why didn't the other mother force Coraline to stay with her when she slept in her world for the first time?

Tags: coraline

When Coraline sleeps in the other mother's house for the first two or three nights, she wakes up in her real room, as if she just apparated in her sleep. However, when she wanted to return home and went to sleep in the other mother's world, she did not wake up in her own bed. If the other mother could force her to stay in her world like that, why didn't she just force her to stay there during the first or the second night? I have only watched the movie. Is this explained any better in the book?

Comment: Not explained any better in the book. The implication seems to be that she wants Coraline to decide of her own free will.

Answer (score 2):

The Other Mother is a fairy monster who has to obey fairy tale rules. And those rules are: you can choose to stay and if you want to stay you only have to say so, to explicitly express your desire.

If you do so, you can choose to play the game for your freedom. And if you lose, the host gets to eat you. In fact, Coraline promises that she will give herself willingly if she loses. She couldn't do anything to Coraline until the girl said that she doesn't want to leave for her home and parents in "real world". As a result, Coraline couldn't find her parents for the whole day. But Coraline also didn't explicitly say that she wants to stay, so there was some wriggle room.

The point is, be careful what you wish for out loud. Somebody might be listening.